# 'MIMEText' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mime, mime-message

Hi I am trying to work out why I am getting this error. Its got me a little baffled. I am using Python 3.6

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
message_text = 'this is a test body'
message = MIMEText(message_text)
message['to'] = 'me@example.com'
message['from'] = 'you@example.com'
message['subject'] = 'test subject'
logger.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
logger.debug(message)
logger.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
try:
  raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
except Exception as e:
  logger.debug('---------------')
  logger.debug(e)
  logger.debug('---------------')
```

And this is the output.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii". 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit.  
to: me@example.com
from: you@example.com
subject: test subject

this is a test body
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

---------------
'MIMEText' object has no attribute 'encode'
---------------
```

Comment: I don't know MIMEText, but bviously your `MIMEText` is not a string, so you need check the doc's for a way how to get hands on the string inside and apply encode then to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIMEText does not have an `.encode()` method, it looks like you want the `as_string()` method.

`message.as_string()` will return the following string:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
to: me@example.com
from: you@example.com
subject: test subject

this is a test body
```

Give this a try:

```
raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
```